# For what $n$ are these polynomials separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I already know that $P$ is separable iif $\gcd(P,P')=1$

I want to check for what $n$ these two polynomials are separable.

1. $P(X)=X^n-1\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$
2. $P(X)=X^n-1\in \mathbb{F}_4[X]$

For both polynomials we can compute $P'(X)= nX^{n-1}$. We see that the only factors of $P'$ are $X^k$ for $k=1,...,n-1$ but these are not factors of $P$ since it hasn't $0$ as root. So $\gcd(P,P')=1$ $\forall n$

For the second one I need to look at two cases.

2.1: $n\not \equiv 0\mod 4$, then it's the same reasoning as for (1).

2.2. $n\equiv 0\mod 4$ $\Rightarrow$ $P'(X) = nX^{n-1}=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\gcd(P,P') = P$

Is that OK?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @DavidHill Thank you.

Comment: But what about $n=2$?

Comment: @Mindlack what do you mean?

Comment: What is $(X^2-1)’$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$?

Comment: @Mindlack it's 2X, isn't it?

Comment: Doesn’t $2X$ vanish in $\mathbb{F}_4$? Why is it coprime to $X^2-1$?

Comment: Ah that's true. I was confusing $\mathbb{F} _4$ with $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Mindlack does it fix my attempt if I'm using mod 2 instead of mod 4?

Comment: I think so. But note that even in $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$, $(X^2-1,(X^2-1)’)$ isn’t the unit ideal.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll think more about it.